# Unable to connect to AWS centos instance from Oracle Linux Virtualbox

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, centos, oraclelinux

When I am trying to connect to AWS CentOS instance from Linux Oracle I am getting below error:

```
ssh -i "/LinuxTest.pem" centos@ec2-3-7-55-40.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Load key "/LinuxTest.pem": invalid format
```

While I am able to connect with same key from Windows(which is the host machine) from Putty after converting the .pem to .ppk.

Answer (score 1):

Use a credential file generated by the ssh-keygen(1) application, not an AWS since you are connecting to the VM itself and not to an AWS facility.

Comment: Sorry If I have not made myself clear. I am trying to connect to aws from Linux guest machine on virtualbox and windows is the host machine. I am able to connect to aws instance from windows host machine successfully using the key generate from aws and converting it using puttygen.